# The same code is running on the jupyter note book but not on the Spyder. Can anyone please tell me that why this is giving error?

Tags: python

```
import math
import unittest 
class Calculator:
    def  __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def is_sum(a,b):
        return a+b
is_sum(10,5)  #Here is the issue
import unittest
class CalculatorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.Calculator.is_sum.is_number(a))
        self.assertTrue(self.Calculator.is_sum.is_number(b))
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: add your problem in post don't add it in the question title

Comment: The is_sum function 's scope is within the class `Calculator`. Inorder to access it's function, create an object of the class and call the function.

Comment: What's the error?